# JBoss7 LDAP access by role with Guvnor 5.4

Tags: jboss, ldap, jboss7.x, drools-guvnor

I'm trying to enable access to Guvnor through LDAP defined roles. I've managed to get JBoss to connect to my LDAP server and authenticate by user, but I have no idea how to do that by role instead. What I want is to allow, for example, all users with the Role "Guvnor Administrator" to log into the Guvnor page.

Can anyone help me with this? I've tried several configurations, including modifying the web.xml in guvnor.war, but the closest I could get to role-based authorization was through configuring user permissions in the Guvnor administration page.

My standalone.xml:

```
<security-domain name="drools-guvnor" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
                            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://myLDAPHost"/>
                            <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="ou=Users,dc=proj,dc=com"/>
                            <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=Roles, dc=flow,dc=com"/>
                            <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                            <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="searchScope" value="ONELEVEL_SCOPE"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

beans.xml:

```
    <security:IdentityImpl> <s:modifies/>
               <!-- JAAS based authentication -->
              <security:authenticatorName>jaasAuthenticator</security:authenticatorName>  
         </security:IdentityImpl>
         <security:jaas.JaasAuthenticator>
              <s:modifies/>
              <security:jaasConfigName>drools-guvnor</security:jaasConfigName>
         </security:jaas.JaasAuthenticator> 

    <!-- SECURITY AUTHORIZATION CONFIGURATION --> <!-- This is used to enable or disable role-based authorization. By default it is disabled. -->        
        <guvnorSecurity:RoleBasedPermissionResolver>
              <s:modifies/>
              <guvnorSecurity:enableRoleBasedAuthorization>true</guvnorSecurity:enableRoleBasedAuthorization>
         </guvnorSecurity:RoleBasedPermissionResolver>

  <weld:scan>
    <!-- Disable the seam-security by drools rules 
    <weld:exclude name="org.jboss.seam.security.permission.RuleBasedPermissionResolver"/>-->
    <!-- TODO remove me when GUVNOR-1196 is fixed -->
    <weld:exclude name="org.drools.guvnor.gwtutil.**"/>
    <weld:exclude name="org.drools.guvnor.client.**"/>
  </weld:scan>
```

Comment: Best mention what version of Guvnor. This kind of thing changes considerably across versions.

Comment: thanks for the tip :) specified the guvnor version on the title